# How to create MongoDB Update query to update certain elements in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with thousands of documents. I have different steps in this collection and their steps status is completed. I want to update particular steps status from Completed to Open. For example, I want to update status to "Open"only for steps three and four and the document overAllStatus to Started. I want to do this where  "executionId" is "20200622104036256".

My documents/json structure. Collection name order_status

```
   {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ef03d8f5f5775000921e5b9"),
  "executionId" : "20200622104036256",
  "stateNumber" : "123456",
  "overAllStatus" : "Completed",
  "steps" : [{
      "name" : "Step One",
      "status" : "Completed"
    }, {
     "name" : "Step Two",
      "status" : "Completed"
    }, {
     "name" : "Step Three",
       "status" : "Completed"
    }, {
     "name" : "Step Four",
       "status" : "Completed"
    }],
  "ABC" : {
    "status" : "Completed"
  }
  
}
```

After i execute the shell update script/query. All the documents where the "executionId" is "20200622104036256" will be looking as below

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ef03d8f5f5775000921e5b9"),
  "executionId" : "20200622104036256",
  "stateNumber" : "123456",
  "overAllStatus" : "Started",
  "steps" : [{
      "name" : "Step One",
      "status" : "Completed"
    }, {
     "name" : "Step Two",
      "status" : "Completed"
    }, {
     "name" : "Step Three",
       "status" : "Open"
    }, {
     "name" : "Step Four",
       "status" : "Open"
    }],
  "ABC" : {
    "status" : "Completed"
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query :**

```
/** Using updateMany to update multiple documents matching certain criteria */
db.order_status.updateMany(
  { executionId: "20200622104036256" }, // Filtering for specific docs
  { $set: { overAllStatus: "Started", "steps.$[element].status": "Open" } }, // Update specific element in an array
  { arrayFilters: [{ "element.name": { $in: ["Step Three", "Step Four"] } }] } // Returns specific elements in `steps` array that matches criteria for update
);
```

**Ref :** [arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#specify-arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations)

**Note :**

If you wanted to update `overAllStatus` field only in case where, for documents with `executionId: "20200622104036256"` and have at-least one step element with name either "Step Three" or "Step Four" - then your filter part of `.updateMany()` should be :

```
{"executionId" : "20200622104036256", 'steps.name': { $in : ["Step Three","Step Four"]}}
```